File-backed mmap in /var/run not showing in pmap output
I have created a file-backed mmap where the file is located in the /var/run/ folder. However, when I check the output of the pmap command for the running process, the file-backed entry is not visible.
Is this behavior due to the file being located in /var/run?

Can't reproduce. It shows up in pmap when I make a program that does that. Please add enough details that other people can reproduce what you're seeing.

Thanks @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica for inputs it seems the mapping was removed due to some error. Currently not able to replicate this will update once get this issue again with more details
